# Kitchen cabinet hinge issue

Tags: kitchens

I have a face frame, full overlay cabinet that I want to open 170 degrees. I bought a Blum hinge 170-degree face frame hinge but, when installed the cabinet door is over too far and the adjustments on the hinge to move the door are not enough to compensate. Is there something else to do or another type of hinge that will allow a 170 swing?

Comment: Pictures would help.

Comment: There are multiple versions of that Blum hinge (and if other hinges) for varying amounts of overlay or inset of the door. Sounds like you just don't have the right hinge.